# Firefox extension elements id

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Can someone tell me where can I find the ids of browser elements in Firefox?

I want to put a `menupopup` in the web developer section in Firefox and I need an `id` to put into the `insertafter` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the IDs in the [source code of `browser.xul`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.xul) as well as its include files like [`browser-sets.inc`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc). Alternatively, you can inspect the browser window at runtime using the [DOM Inspector extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/).

Answer (score 0):

The web developer menupopup can be found in:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-appmenu.inc#144

```
<menupopup id="appmenu_webDeveloper_popup">
  <menuitem id="appmenu_devToolbox">
  ...
```

---

Alternatively, If you have DOM Inspector, open it and go to menu:

File->Inspect **Chrome** Document->`chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`

(*browser.xul* should usually be the first item (1) with the same title as the browser's taskbar or current tab).

Then search for ID=`appmenu_webDeveloper_popup`.  Many of the other menus can be found at ID=`mainPopupSet`.

---

Also, this scratchpad snippet lists the IDs of child elements contained in the web developer menupopup (set scratchpad environment to *browser*, execute as *display* to output the result ):

```
var webdev=document.getElementById("appmenu_webDeveloper_popup");
var idList=Array.prototype.slice.call(webdev.children).map(function(node){
    return node.id;
}).filter(function(id)id);
idList.join("\n");
```