# key in xul file of firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, xul, saucelabs

While working on an existing open source firefox addon to improve it I found the following code piece but couldn't figure out the usage of key work "key" in key="selenium-builder-run-key" line

```
    <menupopup id="menuWebDeveloperPopup"> 
        <menuitem
            label="&runseleniumbuilder;"
            key="selenium-builder-run-key"
            oncommand="bridge.boot()" />
    </menupopup>
```

What does it do though I am aware that menuWebDeveloperPopup is id for web developer menu present in tool bar.

What does

```
            key="selenium-builder-run-key"
```

do in the above snippet?

strangely one para below the above one is

```
    <menupopup id="appmenu_webDeveloper_popup"> 
        <menuitem
            label="&runseleniumbuilder;"
            key="selenium-builder-run-key"
            oncommand="bridge.boot()" />
    </menupopup>
```

but I couldn't find any dom with such a ID though [Firefox extension elements id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736071/firefox-extension-elements-id) mentions that appmenu_webDeveloper_popup could be found in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.xul. I dont find it. Is it removed or deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` attribute is a reference to a XUL [`<key>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/key) that specifies a keyboard shortcut for that menuitem.

In this, case, the add-on contains:

```
<key id="selenium-builder-run-key"
                modifiers="accel alt"
                key="B"
                oncommand="bridge.boot()" />
```

Which means a `<menuitem>` with `key="selenium-builder-run-key"` can be activated by pressing "Control-Alt-B" on the keyboard (or Command-Opt-B on a Mac).

As for your other question, [searching for that ID in an old version of Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-esr24/search?string=appmenu_webDeveloper_popup) finds it in one of the files included by `browser.xul`, but it looks like it's been removed in newer versions of Firefox.